# You must call enableActiveRecord() on your client before calling this method

Tags: coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I am using coinbase-php library.

I am trying to get addresses of primary account using following code.

```
$primaryAccount = $this->client->getPrimaryAccount();
$addresses = $primaryAccount->getAddresses();
```

Getting "enableActiveRecord() on your client before calling this method" error.

Comment: Didn't get why my question was downgraded!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using the snippet, I should have enabledActiveRecord by

```
$this->client->enableActiveRecord();
```

Soon after

```
$this->client = Client::create($this->configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it helps.

Set account as primary.

**Example request:**

```
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b/primary
&nbsp; -X POST
&nbsp; -H &apos;Authorization: Bearer abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c&apos;

Response (200)
{
   "data": 
   {
      "id": "82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b",
      "name": "New hot wallet",
      "primary": true,
      "type": "wallet",
      "currency": "BTC",
      "balance": 
      {
         "amount": &quot;0.00000000",
         "currency": "BTC"
      },
      "native_balance": 
      {
         "amount&quot;: "0.00",
         "currency&quot;: "USD"
      },
      "created_at": "2015-03-31T15:21:58-07:00",
      "updated_at": "2015-03-31T15:21:58-07:00",
      "resource": "account",
      "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b"
   }
}
```